# Visual Studio 2015 CTP6 Setup Stuck on Applying Optional Items

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I've been trying to Install Visual Studio 2015 CTP 6 from more than 2 hours. The progress bar around Acquiring has been 100%, but the progress around Applying Optional Items is stuck since 2+ hours.
I'm currently trying to install it over Microsoft Windows 7 SP1.

[image]

1. Any Help regarding how long it's going to take?
2. How can I diagnose that something isn't broken - so that I can know why the setup is not completing after such a long time? Probably what the setup is currently doing?
3. Any Reasonable workaround??

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Optional items can be several GB's. In the temp dir, there will be some setup.log file.

Comment: Along with clearing temp folder please also disable any anti-virus running on your system and run setup as admin. Here is how I resolved this issue on my system http://www.codewithasp.net/2015/09/solution-for-visual-studio-2015-installation-stuck.html

Answer (score 17):

If you Open the task manager there is a is a sub installer running that is installing the optional items. Just kill that process and the installation will complete. I faced the same issue with visual studio ctp5.

If you repair the installation after that it will install all the missing components again.

Note: I faced this issue while using the ISO installer as well.

Comment: Thanks, ending the "SecondaryInstaller.exe" background process allowed my installer to get past the optional items finally

Comment: You are awesome man, this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: What do you mean by "repair the installation?"

Comment: @wcochran Just run the setup again and it will show repair installation option there or go to control panel -> programs and features and you can repair the installation from there

Answer (score 2):

The visual studio 2015 CTP 6 setup goes online, and downloads several packages on the backend. This process takes plenty of time due to the fact - that it download several packages ,e.g. Android SDK, Build Tools, and lots of others. 
Here's the detailed answer to all the points in question.

1. It took around 3 Hours for me to complete the setup. Mainly- it depends on internet connection, Make sure to disable any parallel downloads, so that the background processes of visual studio can work on full throttle and download as quick as possible.
2. In order to diagnose, how much of the process has been completed - We can check the log of process. You can open the %temp% directory by typing in start, and by sorting the temp files by last modified - in order to see the progress.
3. Reasonable workaround is patience only. Just wait, and continue looking at log files in %temp% directory.

Answer (score 0):

The iso installer (instead of the web installer) seems less prone to hangs. Regardless, I have not had a problem with corruption when aborting the installer and restarting it. It will often run correctly the second time (or third) time.